# Ackermann function is not primitive recursive

Tags: logic, recursion, computability, ackermann-function

The function of the Ackermann function is defined as $$ A_{0}(y)= y+1$$ $$ A_{x+1}(0)= A_{x}(1)$$ $$ A_{x+1}(y +1)= A_{x}(A_{x+1}(y))$$

I want to show that the function of ackermann is primitive recursive, showing  that for all function primitive recursive $f$ exist a number m such that   $f(x_{1}, \dots , x_{k}) < A_{m}(x_{1} + \dots + x_{k})$  for the basic functions (successor, zero, projections) and the composition I did not have problem but for recursion scheme i could not show.

Suppose that $g$ is a $k$-ary function and $h$ a   $k+2$- ary and let a function $f$  which is $k +1$- ary obtained by the recursion scheme applied to $f$ and  $h$.
Supposing that one exists $r$ such that $g(x_{1}, \dots , x_{k})<A_{r}(x_{1}+ \dots + x_{k})$ and exist $s$ such that $h(y_{1}, \dots , y_{k +2})<A_{r}(y_{1}+ \dots + y_{k+2})$ we should find a $q$ such that $f(x_{1}, \dots , x_{k}, n)<A_{q}(x_{1}+ \dots + x_{k} +n)$. I take $q= 1 + max\{r,s\}$ and I try to show by induction on n, for the base case we have $f(x_{1}, \dots , x_{k}, 0)=g(x_{1}, \dots x_{k})< A_{r}(x_{1}+ \dots + x_{k})<A_{q}(x_{1}+ \dots + x_{k})$
Now assuming that $f(x_{1}, \dots , x_{k}, n)<A_{q}(x_{1}+ \dots + x_{k} +n)$ want to show that$f(x_{1}, \dots , x_{k}, n+1)=h(x_{1}, \dots x_{k}, f(x_{1} \dots , x_{k}, n),n)<A_{q}(x_{1}+ \dots + x_{k} +(n+1))$ but I could not show it.

Any hint is welcome. Thanks

Comment: I thought that for primitive recursive, the "recursions" had to have an *a priori* limit on the number of allowable recursions.  In computer programming language, "recursive" allows `for(x=0;f(x);x++)`, whereas "primitive recursive" only allows `for(x=0;f(x)&&(x<y);x++)`.

Comment: See [Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) and [this paper](http://basics.sjtu.edu.cn/~liguoqiang/teaching/comp13/materials/Ackermann.pdf)

Comment: @user67427 The title says "the ackermann-function is NOT primtive recursive". In the body, you want to show that the ackermann-function is primitive recursive.